# How does Typescript know where dist/index.js is, if it doesn't exist?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

There is something I don't understand about this. I am trying to learn Typescript and I got me this boilerplate code using Snowpack and it contains an index.html file which refers to "dist/index.js" as its script, look below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-snowpack-app" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/index.css" />
    <title>Snowpack App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img id="img" src="/logo.svg" />
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <script type="module" src="/dist/index.js"></script>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

This index.html thing is in the "public" folder. I also have "index.ts" file in the "src" folder, which only does a **console.log("hello is this typescript or javascript idk")**. It does give me this console log so it seems to be working.

What I don't understand is how the index.html tries to look for a folder "dist" containing a "index.js" file while neither the "dist" folder nor the "index.js" file exist. I also have a node_modules folder but it doesn't exist there either.

How does this work? Is the "dist" folder simulated or something, while containing a non-existing index.js file when this whole thing is running?

Comment: are you using any code builder like webpack?

Comment: @brk Yes. Sorry I had no clue that that was important. I am using Snowpack. 
For clearance, I got this thing from a YouTube tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jBmrduvKl5w

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Typescript itself doesn't know except that when you compile **all your other js files** the compiler (babel/webpack etc.) will generate a `dist/index.js` file.

Basically it's like compiling your C++ file to build Google Chrome. C++ does not know where or what the `chrome.exe` file is except that the build script/command tells it to generate `chrome.exe` from source code.

> Note: Depending on your build process the directory can be named **dist** or **build** or **target** or **mootdrafters_website** etc. The react-create-app script for example does not name it's output folder **dist** but generates **build/index.js** instead.

Comment: Your confusion is probably caused by the fact that Typescript compiles source code to javascript source code. If you saw a build script/makefile generate `index.exe` for example you would probably be less confused.

Answer (score 0):

How did you run your boilerplate code, by using cmd 'snowpack dev'?

If so, snowpack provides a web server running in nodejs process, and the 'src/index.ts' has been transpiled to 'dist/index.js' (in memory).When your browser requests 'dist/index.js' , the snowpack server responses the file content in memory.That's why there is no such 'dist' folder.

More futher, if you try cmd 'snowpack build', you will see the 'dist' folder.

'snowpack dev' for development, using a web server locally

'snowpack build' for production, you can deploy the 'dist' folder to any other web servers